# NOTICE Undefined Offset line 23

Tags: php

I have a problem in my php file. Eclipse cannot read and store it to my sqlite database because of the notice. a little help please. Thankyou in advance. Here's my code.

```
<?php

include("config.php");
$x =  $_GET["quiz"];
$query1 = "SELECT id, quiz, question FROM mdl_quiz_question_instances WHERE quiz = $x";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
$obj = array();
$ques = array();
$i = 0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    $obj[$i]['id'] = $row["id"];
    $obj[$i]['quiz'] = $row["quiz"]; 
    $obj[$i]['question'] = $row["question"];
    $ques[$i] = $obj[$i]['question'];
    $i++; 
}

$query2 = "SELECT id, category, questiontext, qtype FROM mdl_question";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$obj2 = array();
$j = 0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    if($ques[$j] == $row["id"]){
    $obj2[$j]['id'] = $row["id"];
    $obj2[$j]['category'] = $row["category"];
    $obj2[$j]['questiontext'] = $row["questiontext"];
    $obj2[$j]['qtype'] = $row["qtype"];
    $j++;
    }
}

echo json_encode($obj2);
mysql_close();  


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
if ($ques[$j] == $row["id"]) {
}
```

to

```
if (isset($ques[$j]) && $ques[$j] == $row["id"]) {
}
```

It’s probable that your first query will only return a number of results less than or equal to the number of results returned from the second query. Since your `$ques` array is populated by the first query, you can’t access it while looping through the results of the second query without checking that the key you are looking for exists.

Also based on a guess, this code will not match up values from the two different queries the way you are expecting.

Comment: Thankyou for a quick response. It fixed the output thanks! but regarding to the two different queries, I just actually need the results from the second query. but it has to be determined by the question id from the first query.

Comment: @user3022926 A problem I see is that you are trying to match them up based on what order they are retrieved from the database, not based on ID. I suggest combining everything into one statement using a `JOIN` or to give your `$ques` array keys based on `id`.